# Questions regarding update of table on Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I'm trying to update ps_stock_available when I modify the product on Prestashop. But it's unsuccessfull. Could you help me please ?

```
public function hookActionUpdateQuantity(array $params) 
    {
        $id_product = $params['id_product'];
        $product = new Product((int)$id_product);
        $id_category = $product->id_category_default;
        $db = \Db::getInstance();     
    
        $request_loc='SELECT location FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_location` WHERE `id_category` = '.(int)$id_category;
        $location = $db->getValue($request_loc);

      $request_id_stock='SELECT id_stock_available FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'stock_available` WHERE `id_product` = '.(int)$id_product;
       $id_stock_available = $db->getValue($request_id_stock);
             
       $result = $db->update('stock_available', array('location' => $location), '`id_stock_available` = '.(int)$id_stock_available);
     
    }
```

I have written this code but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

in order to accomplish this task I would rely to the native StockAvailable class metehods **getStockAvailableIdByProductId()** and **setLocation**()  (check the classes/stock/StockAvailable.php file).

Anyway your code seems to be correct, so I would definitely check for undefined variables and/or something not working in the $db->update statement.

In case, you can change it to :

```
$db->execute('UPDATE '._DB_PREFIX_.'stock_available SET `location` = "'.pSQL($location).'" WHERE id_stock_available = '.(int)$id_stock_available;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for tips, I have updated my code following your instructions. It still doesn't work.What i don't understand, I have tested it and put it into ps_product "Reference" location and id_stock_available. It's working... I have tested to update ps_product location, it's working also *_* . But i can't update location in ps_stock_available.

Comment: In order to troubleshoot I would definitely try to "var_dump()" the latest query and try launching it from a MySQL client to see if there's something wrong.

Comment: I have put a var_dump. It's getting even more weird. Now, I got the location fulfilled but when I delete the var_dump, the location is empty. I think there is something else after the update which is deleting the location put in the stock_available. I'm not sure about this hypothesis.